# htaccess to subdirectory without changing address bar URL?

Tags: .htaccess, subdirectory

I've a problem with `htaccess` and none of the suggested solution wont work. So I hope that someone of you has the right solution for me, please.

My application is installed in a subfolder hierarchy and I try to get `/dist/WSCM2` as the root directory which is also shown in the address bar of the browser.

With my current `htaccess` I can access my site, but the redirection is shown in the address bar, too

```
RewriteCond $1 !^dist/WSCM2($|/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /dist/WSCM2/ [L]
```

How can I prevent showing the subdirectory?

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on

# external redirect with subfolder
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+dist/WSCM2(\s|/)
RewriteRule ^dist/WSCM2(/.*)? $1 [R=301,L,NE]

# internal rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dist/WSCM2($|/)
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /dist/WSCM2/$1 [L]
```

Comment: nope. it doesn't work. I had to change `RewriteCond $1 !^/dist/WSCM2($|/)` to `RewriteCond $1 !^dist/WSCM2($|/)` because of an 500 to get to work but then the address bar changed again to `dist/WSCM2 `

Comment: I had copied too quickly. Try now.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. Address bar shows .../dist/WSCM2... again

Comment: Did you clear your cache or try with other browser ? No others rules before ?

Comment: yes I cleared everything and turned of any other rules before

Comment: And other rules after ?

Comment: there are no further rules after

Comment: And no rules in subdirectories ?

Comment: also not :-( There are no rules.